# What building is there? vs What is that building?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Please, could you explain the difference of these sentences:

> What building is there?

vs

> What is that building?

What meanings are there? In what situations can I use them?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What building is there?

This means we're talking about a location (like "On Third Street near Main") and the speaker wants to know what building is at that location.

> What is that building?

This means we've encountered a building (maybe we're standing near it, or looking at a photograph of it), and the speaker wants to know what building it is (for example, "the Transamerica Pyramid").